# Equivalent Cauchy sequences.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, self-learning, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Hi everyone I'm having a bad time with two questions in the Analysis book of Terry Tao. I finally finished one of the exercises and I'm wondering if the next reasoning is correct or maybe needs some changes:

**Definitions**:

Two sequence are equivalence $\iff$ $(\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+\,) ( \, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\,) \text{ s.t. }(\, \forall n \ge N\, (|a_n-b_n|\le \varepsilon)\,)  $

(where $\mathbb{Q}^+$ is a positive rational number).

**Exercise**: Show that if $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalences secuences of rationals. Then  $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$  is a Cauchy sequence.

Proof: 
We suppose that $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and  also we may assume that $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent sequences; we wish to show that $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Let $\, \varepsilon $ be  an arbitrary positive integer, we shall show that there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_j-b_k| \le \varepsilon$ for all $\,j,k \ge N$. Let $\gamma$ be a positive rational number such that $\gamma < \varepsilon$. Since $\langle a_n \rangle _{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence it follows that there is some $N'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{j'}-a_{k'} |\le \varepsilon-\gamma$ for all $j',k' \ge N'$.

Now we set $|a_n-b_n|\le \frac{\gamma}{2}\,$  for all $n \ge M$. So either $M>N'$ or $\,M\le N'$ by the ordering of natural numbers.

If $M>N'$ we choose $j',k'\ge M$ and then, we have that:

$|b_{j'} -b_{k'}|-|a_{j'} -a_{k'}|\le|(a_{j'} -a_{k'})- (b_{j'} -b_{k'})| \le |a_{j'} -b_{j'}|+|a_{k'} -b_{k'}|\le \gamma$

And so we have that $|b_{j'} -b_{k'}|\le \gamma +|a_{j'} -a_{k'}| \le \varepsilon$, it follows that $|b_{j'} -b_{k'}|\le \varepsilon$ for all $j',k'\ge M$ as desired.

On the other hand if $\,M \le N'$ we choose a $n\ge N'$ and a similar argument give us that $|b_{j'} -b_{k'}|\le \varepsilon$ for all $j',k'\ge N'$ as desired.

So in either case, $|b_{j} -b_{k}|\le \varepsilon\,$ for all $\,j,k \ge N$ and hence the sequence $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

To conclude note that the converse may be disposed with no additional work, by applying the same argument with the roles of $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ interchanged, i.e., where $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Thanks in advance as usual.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use the estimate $|b_n-b_m| \le |b_n -a_n| + |a_n-a_m| + |a_m -b_m|$, and choose $N$ such that $|b_k-a_k| < \frac{1}{3}\epsilon$ and $|a_n-a_m| < \frac{1}{3}\epsilon$ for $k,m,n \ge N$.

Comment: @copper.hat: could you explain it, please? and Do you think my attempt is correct?

Comment: I can explain my approach (see below), but I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to above, and there are a number of issues. For example, if $\epsilon$ is rational, you could take $\gamma = \epsilon$, but a later step in the proof may fail in this case (since $\epsilon-\gamma = 0$, and selecting the first $N'$ may be impossible).

Comment: @copper.hat: I saw my notebook and it is a typo I wanted to put $\gamma < \varepsilon$ which work around the issue, I think. But yes, you proof is easier. Thanks. Let me try to clarify my attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be give. With loss of generality, we may assume $\epsilon$ is rational. Suppose $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and $b_n$, $a_n$ are equivalent.

Choose $N$ such that $|b_k-a_k| < \frac{1}{3} \epsilon$ and $|a_n-a_m| < \frac{1}{3} \epsilon$ whenever $k,m,n  \ge N$. We can do this because $a_n$ is Cauchy, and $a_n,b_n$ are equivalent.

Then if $n,m \ge N$, we have
$|b_n-b_m| \le |b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a_m|+|a_m-b_m| \le \frac{1}{3} \epsilon + \frac{1}{3} \epsilon + \frac{1}{3} \epsilon = \epsilon$.
Hence $b_n$ is Cauchy.

Reversing the roles of $a_n,b_n$ finishes the proof.

Comment: You have a typo here, I think you mean to say "without lose of generality".

Comment: I just wrote this proof using about 4 times as many words :) Thanks from almost 6 years in the future for showing me how to write this proof better!