# Two sequences are equivalent. Prove that one is Cauchy iff the other is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

This question has already been asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490236/equivalent-cauchy-sequences)

---

Let $ϵ>0$ be given. With loss of generality, we may assume $ϵ$ is rational. Suppose $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and $b_n, a_n$ are equivalent.

Choose N such that $|b_k−a_k|<\frac13\epsilon$ and $|a_n−a_m|<\frac13\epsilon$ whenever $k,m,n≥N.$ We can do this because an is Cauchy, and $a_n,b_n$ are equivalent.

Then if $n,m≥N$, we have

$|b_n−b_m|≤|b_n−a_n|+|a_n−a_m|+|a_m−b_m|≤\frac13\epsilon+\frac13\epsilon+\frac13\epsilon=ϵ.$ Hence $b_n$ is Cauchy.

Reversing the roles of $a_n,b_n$ finishes the proof.

---

What I cannot follow in the answer is why we can assume:

$|b_m-b_n|\le|b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a_m|+|a_m-b_m|$

Am I missing something huge here or I am out of the loop on some standard inequality?

Comment: This is an easy inequality to prove. It's usually given as an exercise. What have you tried?

Comment: What does "two sequences are equivalent" mean? That their difference converges to zero?

Comment: Yes. That their distance from each other eventually gets less than any rational number.

Comment: Thanks @atecce I was just about to post my proof of this problem, but thanks to you i dont have to type it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard trick in analysis-y proofs: Add $0$ creatively, and use the triangle inequality. In particular, we have

$$|a - b| = |a - (c - c) - b| = |(a - c) + (c - b)| \le |a - c| + |c - b|$$

for any $a, b, c$. This can be generalized to $3$ (as in your case) or more terms.

Answer (score 2):

It is the triangle inequality:

$$|b_m-b_n|=|(b_n-a_n)+(a_n-a_m)+(a_m-b_m)|\le|b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a_m|+|a_m-b_m|$$

Comment: Thank you both! Sorry it was so easy for you guys.