# Proof Verification: Regarding equivalent sequences and Cauchy sequences, Tao Analysis I: Exercise 5.2.1.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

**Proposition:** If $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent sequences of rationals, then $(a_n)_{n}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence iff $(b_n)_{n}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

*Identical questions:* (1)[Equivalent Cauchy sequences.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490236/equivalent-cauchy-sequences?noredirect=1&lq=1)
(2)[Two sequences are equivalent. Prove that one is Cauchy iff the other is Cauchy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784491/two-sequences-are-equivalent-prove-that-one-is-cauchy-iff-the-other-is-cauchy)

***Reason for duplicating:*** I did it somewhat differently. So I'm not certain if I did it correctly. Would be grateful if someone could point out erroneous areas of the proof and how it could be better.

> **Definition $\bf 5.2.6$** (Equivalent sequences). Two sequences $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ are *equivalent* iff for each rational $\varepsilon>0$, the sequences  $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and  $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ are eventually $\epsilon$-close. In other words, $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$ and $b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots$ are equivalent iff for every rational $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\geqslant0$ such that $|a_n-b_n|\leqslant\varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant N$.

Proof: Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be equivalent sequences and $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then, by definition of equivalent sequences \begin{align}\forall\epsilon\in \Bbb{Q}^{+}\exists n\in\Bbb{N}:( n\geqslant 1 \land \vert a_n-b_n\vert\leqslant\epsilon).\end{align} By definition of a Cauchy sequence, \begin{align}\forall\epsilon\in\Bbb{Q}^+\exists n\in\Bbb{N}: (j,k\geqslant n \Rightarrow \vert a_j=a_k\vert\leqslant\epsilon).\end{align}
Note that \begin{align}\vert b_j-b_k\vert=\vert(a_k-b_k)-(a_k-b_j)\vert\ \quad and \quad \vert(a_k-b_k)-(a_k-b_j)\vert\leqslant\vert a_k-b_k\vert +\vert a_k-b_j\vert\end{align} Thus, $\vert b_j-b_k\vert\leqslant\vert a_k-b_k\vert +\vert a_k-b_j\vert\leqslant\epsilon'+\vert a_k-b_j\vert$ such that $\epsilon'\in\Bbb{Q}^+$ and $\forall x\geqslant k$, $\vert a_k-b_k\vert\leqslant\epsilon'$. Also, $\vert a_k-b_j\vert=\vert(a_j-b_j)-(a_j-a_k)\vert\leqslant\vert a_j-b_j\vert +\vert a_j-a_k\vert$ such that $\vert a_j-b_j\vert\leqslant\overline{\epsilon}$ and $\vert a_j-a_k\vert\leqslant\epsilon^*$, since $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are equivalent sequences and $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Thus, $\vert a_k-bj\vert\leqslant\vert a_j-b_j\vert + \vert a_j-a_k\vert\leqslant \overline{\epsilon}+\epsilon^*$, and $\vert b_j-b_k\vert\leqslant \vert a_k-b_k\vert +\vert a_k-b_j\vert\leqslant \epsilon'+\vert a_k-b_j\vert\leqslant\epsilon'+\overline{\epsilon}+\epsilon^*$. Since, $\epsilon',\overline{\epsilon},\epsilon^*$ are arbitrary elements in $\Bbb{Q}^+$, then $\epsilon' +\overline{\epsilon}+ \epsilon^*=\hat{\epsilon}\in\Bbb{Q}^+$ is also arbitrary. Therefore, $\forall \hat{\epsilon}\in\Bbb{Q}^+\exists n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that if $j,k\geqslant n$, then $\vert b_j-b_k\vert\leqslant\hat{\epsilon}$, which implies that $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence. The converse of the proposition can be argued backwards.

Comment: putting spaces somewhere wont kill you :)